# Unable to install .net core ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I downloaded a virtual machine from here:
http://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/
And then i followed the steps from the .net core site
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu

And each time i want to install the `.net` core I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2.1-003177
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2.1-003177
osboxes@osboxes:~/Downloads/dotnet-ubuntu-x64.1.0.3$
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set it up and it looks like they messed up the latest build. The instruction says to install with:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2.1-003177
```

However the actual package name is `dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-1-003177` (somehow '2.1' changed to '2-1'). Previous package was 2.1, guessing next one will get corrected.

Also check if everything from install instructions is in place.

1. is /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list present and contains correct entries?
2. run `lsb_release -a` just to make sure the vm is 14.04
3. make sure you've run `sudo apt-get update` - see if it doesn't complain/ignore dot net repo.

If it's all ok, try searching for .net package, maybe the name got changed, e.g. with: `apt-cache search dotnet`

Answer (score 0):

Per the [install instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu), you must first invoke these commands:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/ trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 417A0893
sudo apt-get update
```